# How to find all possible combinations of 5 numbers in an array 0-9

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming and I would like to get all the possible combinations of a one-dimensional array with 5 elements and without numbers repeating for example it starts with `00001`, `00002`, `00003`, ... ,`99999`.

```
int count(){

    while (i<100000){  //loop to go thru all possible combinations

      //std::cout<<i<<"\t";
      if (i>=10000){

    num(i);
    print();

      }


      i++;
    }

  }

void num (int i){   /* method to sort all the number to the array for i */

takeNumbersFromUser=i;      

    for( n=0;n<arraySize;n++){
      if (control==0){
        ar[n]=takeNumbersFromUser % 10;
      }
      else if (control==1){
        temp= takeNumbersFromUser % 100;
        ar[n]=temp/10;
      }
      else if (control==2){
        temp = takeNumbersFromUser % 1000;
        ar[n] = temp/100;
      }
      else if (control==3){
        temp = takeNumbersFromUser % 10000;
        ar[n] = temp/1000;
      }
      else if (control==4){
        temp = takeNumbersFromUser % 100000;
        ar[n] = temp/10000;
      }
      control++;
    }

  }

void print(){  //print out 
      std::cout<<"\n\n\tyou entered "<<takeNumbersFromUser<<"\n\n";
      for (n=5;n>=0;n--){
        std::cout<<ar[n]<<"\t";
      }

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Give a sample example for us to understand better!

Comment: while (i<100000){  //loop to go thru all possible combinations
      
      //std::cout<<i<<"\t";
      if (i>=10000){
 
 num(i);
 print();
 
      }
      
      
      i++;
    }

Comment: //num method   takeNumbersFromUser=i; for( n=0;n<arraySize;n++){
   if (control==0){
     ar[n]=takeNumbersFromUser % 10;
   }
   else if (control==1){
     temp= takeNumbersFromUser % 100;
     ar[n]=temp/10;
   }
   else if (control==2){
     temp = takeNumbersFromUser % 1000;
     ar[n] = temp/100;
   }
   else if (control==3){
     temp = takeNumbersFromUser % 10000;
     ar[n] = temp/1000;
   }
   else if (control==4){
     temp = takeNumbersFromUser % 100000;
     ar[n] = temp/10000;
   }
   control++;}

Comment: You said you don't want to repeat numbers but I suppose you mean digits and 0 can be repeated isn't it ? Well you need to have a look at an algorithm to generate all permutations of a set (digits) and adapt it for your need.

Comment: @Blue_Jay: Edit your question instead of adding unreadable code in comment.

Comment: 0 can be repeated  Jean-Baptiste Yunes

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
// Size of parent array (10^length)
int size = 100000;
// Length of number
int length = 5;
// Two dimensional array to hold the numbers
int** matrix = new int*[size];
// Create all elements in the array
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[length];
    // Temporary variable to "play" with 'i'
    int temp = i;
    for(int j=length-1;j>=0;j--) {
        matrix[i][j] = temp%10;
        temp /= 10;
    }
}
```

I believe this is very simple, and does not require further explanation.
If it does, please ask and I will provide

**EDIT:**

As suggested, you can replace the int* array with:
`new vector<int>[size]`

Then in the `for j` loop, there is no need to create a new array, and you can just use: `matrix[i].push_back(temp%10)`

And finally, to print this, you can do a new `for i` loop, going over the vectors array, and inside to have a foreach loop, something like:

`for(int n : v)
    std::cout << n << " ";`

You can deffinetly should be able to manage from here.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of raw `new`

Comment: @Amit please show me how you will output the results

Comment: @Jarod42 how can i add the vector if it is possible please show me ?

Comment: @Blue_Jay I added an explanation on how to use a vector (great idea), and how to print it.

Comment: what is int n:v ? @Amit

Comment: the i loop will loop how many times ?  why use matrix and vectors ? and ** why not use array ?  the last  two questions are not that important for now but can you please show me the loop .  @Amit